# Alinear <div...> abajo de mi página web

Tags: angular2-template

Estoy trabajando con Angularjs y tengo que mostrar un Template, cuando le doy al boton de informacion se visualiza arriba de todo y quiero que aparezca abajo de todo.

Lo tengo que mostrar en el `_Layout.cshtml`, aqui esta el codigo:

```
<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formAppCtrl">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " style="background-color:#5882FA">
    <div class="container" style="color:white">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="color:#ffffff">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Información", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand"})*@
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "HelpPage" }, null)</li>
                <li><a ui-sref="informacion">Informacion</a></li>
            </ul>
            @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*style="padding-top:0px;*@
@*"container text-center"*@
@*class="body-content"*@


<div class="container text-center" style="padding-top:50px;"   ui-view></div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("SPAViews", required: false)
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/banco")
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Y esto es lo que me aparece en mi `form.html`:

```
<h1>Template info {{}}</h1>
```

Comment: Si pudieras añadir un poco más de información a la pregunta te lo agradecería. Ahora es muy difícil saber lo que quieres realizar.

Comment: Cuando clico un botón que se llama Informacion me tiene que aparecer en la pantalla esto `<h1>Template info {{}} </h1>`  Pero me aparece arriba de todo en la página, encima del formulario que tengo. Entonces con el div que tengo en mi Layout, no se como modificarlo para que me aparezca debajo de todo de la página web.

Comment: algun etiqueta de cierre esta mal, revisa que todas esten cerradas, position:static creo que eso esta mal

Comment: Hola @SilviaGarcia, cuando proporciones información nueva es mucho mejor que edites la pregunta y la indiques ahí. De esta manera, los usuarios pueden ver de una forma más clara toda la información compactada en un solo sitio y es mucho más fácil verlo todo. A lo que me refería antes es que hablas de un formulario y por ejemplo no proporcionas el código referente a dicho formulario. No te digo que pongas todo el html de tu página, sólo las partes relevantes.

Comment: En el div tenía esto : ` <div class="container text-center" style="padding-top:50px;"   ui-view></div>`  y me funciona todo bien, solo es eso, que me aparece arriba de todo. El programa no me da ningun fallo de momento por un mal cierre

Comment: Vale, ahora lo modifico. Perdonad